# SQL Server Query Condition based on input parameters

Tags: sql, sql-server, predict

I need some help with writing a logic for SQL server query. 
I have a table Xyz with three columns

[image]

I have to find all the entities based on user input json.
The logic goes like this.

1. If user input array is {"button"} the query would be 
   "Select * from XYZ where value like '%button%'; "
2. If user input is {"button", "text"} the query would be:
   "Select * from XYZ where value like "%button%" OR value like "%text%"; "
3. If user input is {"button", "text", "page"} the query would be:
   "Select * from XYZ where (value like "%button%" OR value like "%text%") AND (value like "%button%" OR value like "%page%") AND (value like "%page%" OR value like "%text%") AND (value like "%button%" OR value like "%text%" OR value like "%page%"); "
4. If user input is {"button", "text", "page", "element"} the query would be:
   "Select * from XYZ where (value like "%button%" OR value like "%text%" OR value like "%page%") AND (value like "%button%" OR value like "%page%" OR value like "%element%") AND (value like "%text%" OR value like "%page%" OR value like "%element%") AND (value like "%button%" OR value like "%text%" OR value like "%element%") AND (value like "%button%" OR value like "%text%" OR value like "%element%" OR value like '%element%); "
5. If the user input is {"button", "text", "page", "element", "add"} the query logic should make a set of 4 elements in the and condition.

So the logic is that I can receive any kind of user input which could contain "n" elements. For those n elements I need to add n-1 and condition like above and return the result to the user. How can I write a logic to create a query like this? Any suggestions would be helpful.

Comment: Screenshots are not an appropriate way to describe a table schema.  Better to use sql fiddle or similar... then you can mock up your data _and_ your queries

Comment: For `n = 2` case, your given logic has `and`; I think it should be `or`, so that it is in sync for other **n** value(s), except **1**

Answer (score 1):

> If user input is {"button", "text", "page", "element"}

Try the following:

```
SELECT * FROM XYZ 
WHERE ((value like '%button%') + 
       (value like '%text%') + 
       (value like '%page%') + 
       (value like '%element%')) >= 3
```

The basic gist here is that [`Like %..%`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/string-comparison-functions.html#operator_like) is a comparison function, and it will return 0 or 1, depending on the match.

From your problem statement, it seems that either any combination of **n-1** words may be found, *or*, all **n** words may be found.

So, 3 or more input keywords *needs to be* found in the `value`. So, the sum of all these comparison conditions must be **atleast** 3. This should take care off all the possible *combinations*.

So, for **n** number of input(s), you will do something like below:

```
SELECT * FROM XYZ 
WHERE ((value like '%value_1%') + 
       (value like '%value_2%') + 
       ....
       (value like '%value_n-1%') + 
       (value like '%value_n%')) >= n-1
```

For **n = 1**, it will be a special case, and you would simply do the following:

```
SELECT * FROM XYZ 
WHERE value LIKE '%value_1%'
```

Comment: Madhur, Thanks for your input. I updated my logic to add OR condition in between the elements and AND condition between the pairs. Will your logic still work? Also I couldn't get it what is the reason of adding ">= n-1" condition. I tried to execute the logic and I was thrown with the error "Incorrect syntax near '+'".

Comment: @Mohit224 my logic would still work. N is just a variable number. You will need to use its literal value. So let's say if you have 6 input parameters, it would be `>= 5`

Comment: @Mohit224 my comment was only for n=2; your previous logic was correct except n=2

Comment: I get that n is a variable number and I have to replace it with a literal value, I just don't get what is the purpose of that condition. Also how would I fix the "Incorrect syntax near +" error? Yes, you were correct for n=2 I should have OR condition but I also have to use the AND condition between the element combination. Also I am sorry the database is SQL server and not MySQL. I updated the subject.